# How to find the best pairs in for loops in java

Tags: java, eclipse, for-loop

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ContainerCalculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

            //Print the Welcome message
            System.out.println("Welcome to the Container Calculator!");
            System.out.println("====================================");

            //Set the value that users just input to height


            //Variable Declaration

            //Declare the diameter of a cylinder
            float d = 0;
            //Declare the height of a cylinder
            float h = 0;
            //Declare the volume of a cylinder
            float v = 0;
            //Declare the surface are of a cylinder
            float s = 0;



            //Set the value that users just input to diameter

            //Ask users to input the diameter and height of a cylinder

            System.out.print("Enter the diameter of a cylinder (in centimeters): ");
            boolean validDiameter = false;
            do {
                    if (scnr.hasNextInt()){
                            d = scnr.nextInt();
                            if (d <= 0) {
                                    System.out.print("Please enter a positive integer value: ");
                            }
                            else {
                            validDiameter = true;
                    }
            }
                    else {
                            System.out.print("Please enter an integer value (less than 2,147,483,648) as decimal digits: ");
                            scnr.nextLine();
                    }
            } while (!validDiameter);



            System.out.print("Enter the height of a cylinder (in centimeters): ");
            boolean validHeight = false;
            do {
                    if (scnr.hasNextInt()){
                            h = scnr.nextInt();
                            if (h <= 0) {
                                    System.out.print("Please enter a positive integer value: ");
                            }
                            else {
                            validHeight = true;
                    }
                    }
                    else {
                            System.out.print("Please enter an integer value (less than 2,147,483,648) as decimal digits: ");
                            scnr.nextLine();
                    }
            } while (!validHeight);



            //Calculate the value of volume and surface area of the cylinder
            v = (float) ((h*Math.PI*d*d)/4.0);
            s = (float) ((Math.PI*d*d/2 + d*Math.PI*h));

            //Print the value of volume

            System.out.println("A can with a diameter of " + d+ " and a height of "+ h+ " has ");
            //Print with only two places to the right of the decimal
            System.out.printf("\ta volume of %.2f", v );
            System.out.println(",");

            //Print the value of surface area

            //Print with only two places to the right of the decimal
            System.out.printf("\tand a surface area of %.2f", s);
            System.out.println(".");



            double newVolume ;
            double newSurface ;
            double bestVolume = 0;
            double bestSurface = 0;
            double newD = 0;
            double newH = 0;
            double bestD = 0;
            double bestH = 0;               

            for (newD = 1.0; newD <= v; newD++) {
                    for (newH = 1.0; newH <= v; newH++){

                            newVolume = (float) ((newH*Math.PI*newD*newD)/4.0);
                            newSurface = (float) ((Math.PI*newD*newD/2 + newD*Math.PI*newH));

                                if (newVolume > v && newSurface < s)
                            {

                                    bestVolume = newVolume;
                                    bestSurface = newSurface;
                                    bestD = newD;
                                    bestH = newH;

                            }       

                    }
                    }
            System.out.println("*** Surface Area Optimizer ***");

            System.out.println("A can with a diameter of " + bestD+ " and a height of "+ bestH+ " has ");
            //Print with only two places to the right of the decimal
            System.out.printf("\ta volume of %.2f", bestVolume );
            System.out.println(",");

            //Print the value of surface area

            //Print with only two places to the right of the decimal
            System.out.printf("\tand a surface area of %.2f", bestSurface);
            System.out.println(".");

            //Print the end message
            System.out.println("=============================================");
            System.out.println("Thank you for using the Container Calculator." );
            }



    }
```

I wanna ask a question about the for loop part. The expected result of that part is that printing out the smallest surface area. For example, if I input 7 for diameter(d) and 2 for height(s), the newDiameter should be 5 and newheight are should be 4, but my code just prints out 6 and 3. How to improve it?

Comment: Did you step through the code in your debugger?  If not, please do so now.

Comment: inside the for loop. try to change value of newD and newH to "0.0"

Comment: I tried but i still don't know how to store the best diameter and height of the smallest surface area

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in here: `if (newVolume > v && newSurface < s)`

You're trying to find a surface smaller than the previous best surface, so use this condition instead: `if (newVolume >= v && newSurface < bestSurface)`.

In case the entered `h` and `d` were already optimal, the `best*` variables should be initialized to the "original" values, e.g. `bestVolume = v`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136041/discussion-on-answer-by-bjorn-vardal-how-to-find-the-best-pairs-in-for-loops-in).